# Can't install gensim

Tags: python, gensim

When trying to install gensim (with pip install and setup install), it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 19, in <module>
    import ez_setup
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\gensim-0.8.7\ez_setup.py", line 106
    except pkg_resources.VersionConflict, e:
                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I solve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never worked in Gensim, but I'm pretty sure the problem is that you have incompatible versions of it and Python.  The below code uses Python 2.x. syntax.

```
except pkg_resources.VersionConflict, e:
```

In Python 3.x. however, you use `as` instead of `,`:

```
except pkg_resources.VersionConflict as e:
```

Below is a demonstration written in Python 3.x.:

```
>>> try:
...     1/0
... except ZeroDivisionError, e:
  File "<stdin>", line 3
    except ZeroDivisionError, e:
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
>>> try:
...     1/0
... except ZeroDivisionError as e:
...     print(e)
...
division by zero
>>>
```

As you can see, it is your exact same error.

So, to fix the problem, you need to fix the versions.  Either set Python to version 2.x. or get a version of Gensim that runs with Python 3.x.

---

I'm going to move the comment into my post because it is important.  [Here](https://github.com/samantp/gensimPy3) is the link to Gensim for Python 3.x.

Comment: The problem is that I can not find Gensim for Python 3.3. I thought maybe someone has more information on the Gensim module

Comment: Actually, I just found a link: https://github.com/samantp/gensimPy3. Thanks @iCodez

Comment: @user1680859 - Happy to help!  I added that link to my post for any future visitors to this page.  Don't forget to accept an answer though (click the tick).

Comment: I installed it using setup install, but when trying to import from the shell, it gives me: No module named 'gensim'